# How passwd command from non-root account succeeds

Tags: permissions, password, shadow

I am trying to change my password  as a non root user :

```
passwd
```

The data is updated in /etc/shadow, but checking the permission i get:

```
---------- 1 root root 6076 Jan 27 17:14 /etc/shadow
cat /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

Clearly there were no permissions on the file for anyone, 
even then the passwd command succeeds, and  i am indirectly updating data to a non-previliged resource (shadow file)! 
So can anyone explain the mechanism that how the updation takes place in background ?
Explanation with reference to the system calls will be very useful.

Comment: Appart from @D_Bye good answer, you can use `ls -l /etc/shadow` **before** and **after** changing you password. You'll see that is is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `passwd` utility is installed `setuid`, which means that when it runs, it runs *as the user that owns the file*, not as the user that called it. In this case, `passwd` belongs to `root`, so the `setuid` bit causes the program to run with root privileges. It is therefore able to make changes to the `passwd` and `shadow` files.

If you look at the permissions for the `passwd` utility, you'll see something like this:

```
-r-sr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   8.2K 19 Jan 17:24 /usr/bin/passwd
```

This is from my FreeBSD system - what you see will depend on the OS you are using. The `s` in the owner execute position (4th column) indicates the `setuid` bit.

For further reference, the syscall is `setuid`, and is part of the standard C library.